# Determining the bounding rectangle of Mozilla 4's content region

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla, gecko

In versions of Firefox prior to 4, the web content was contained in a window of class "MozillaContentWindowClass". In the newer versions, the entire window is content-based, including toolbars, etc. Can anyone suggest the necessary Javascript code to determine the bounding rectangle (or at the very least the vertical offset) of the web content?

Comment: Would `document.body.offsetHeight` suffice?

Comment: No, that seems to return a much larger value.

Comment: What about `window.innerHeight`? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getBrowser().selectedBrowser.getBoundingClientRect()

Comment: The values this function returns are strange (the presence/absence of the menu bar doesn't seem to affect 'top', for instance), but this is the closest solution I've seen. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`window.innerHeight` will give you the height of the viewport including the horizontal scrollbar (if any).

Comment: It does contain the correct height of the content window, but I actually need the vertical offset of the content in relation to the window's client area. I could subtract innerHeight from the client region's height, but a statusbar (if present) would invalidate my computation.